# python cryptography run-time bindings files in GCS

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I am porting the GCS python client lib. and suffering some problems about dependency.

Because I want to use gcs on the NAS without glibc, I got the error at the code:

**from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials**

the error shows the reason due to lack of gcc

I trace the code and it seems to generate cryptography relative files (like _Cryptography_cffi_36a40ff0x2bad1bae.so) at run-time from the crypto.verify.

Since the machine I used with gcc, is there any way to replace the cryptography library or I could pre-compile and generate the files at my build machine ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cause the compile errors occurred and could not solve easily, I finally use the previous pyOpenssl to solve this problem.